# Conditional return type based on input parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

### Description

I want to return either `string` or `string[]` based on the input parameter. In this case, the input parameter is called `options` and it is the `input` property: `options.input`.

I'm trying to make TypeScript infer it based on this input but I cannot seem to get it to work.

### Types

The types are defined like this.

```
const TextInputTypes = <const>[
    "text",
    "number",
    "password",
    "email",
    "tel",
    "url",
    "search",
    "color",
    "date",
    "time",
    "datetime-local",
    "month",
    "week",
    "range",
    "file",
];
const CheckboxTypes = <const>["checkbox", "radio"];
const SelectTypes = <const>["select"];

type TextType = (typeof TextInputTypes)[number];
type CheckType = (typeof CheckboxTypes)[number] | (typeof SelectTypes)[number];
type InputType = TextType | CheckType;

type PromptOptions = {
    input: InputType;
    placeholder: string;
    entries: { value: string; text: string }[];
};
```

### Example

If `options.input` is in TextType, then it returns `string`, else it returns `string[]`.

### Code

I have tried this without making it work

```
type ReturnType<T extends InputType> = T extends TextType ? string : string[];

const value: ReturnType<typeof options.input>;
```

It is basically within a function like so:

```
function foo = (name: string, options: Options) => {}
```

The output only says `string | string[]`.

Comment: How do you define `Options`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos updated the question and added options.

Comment: I recommend you always return string[], a list with just one element can then still be treated as a list probably simplifying your logic

Comment: @Dexygen That is true. However, if I wanted to do it like this (for future use cases as well), how would I do?

Comment: There is *never* any valid use case IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to the answers from @JDB and @adsy, you can use `extends` to achieve your goal:

```
type StringOrArrayString<T extends PromptOptions> = T extends {input: TextType} ? string : string[];

function foo<T extends PromptOptions>(name: string, options: T): StringOrArrayString<T> {
  // ...
}
```

[Check this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgUwB5QJJgA4FcpwJ4YIQwC8MA2gFAw0wBEUyUdANNbXWFgLYBGCAJ1bsadDAEMIEAO4gBAE2G16CbuICWAGyUdG2tsrpYB%20kfQgJxA4AAsdo0Jrn3688YxcN13BJ7eMobwQAWidgcVNDbnAoOwMOaQQEAGtPAXEwAHNfeNEAMy0cygBdGEkYUEgoAG5KSugYAGEbBGBk3hAkfEJiMnI6W1b2ztZ6dPl1EDpS8vqauvAGgGUETVbcAiJSCjoLNeBmGeI52sooTfgmboRtgApzwhA8y5R0bA2egEpyLj5BYtqDxuzSG1zuQKeTRabQ6XU2EG%20v34AlKAB8YPdNpCVvsPkRETxkQCzhc3jgwWRECgweiQW1rqcgTAAAoCEDcDBQADynMmkG2AG8zOpMDgAFwwMl42oAX0ZFyWUAEIsyXIEAEEBOk8IrlVkADxwGBMBBgeTEVnszk8wKLAB82yNJrNxAFIveEqpeJlMAA-DBoHrMjAJYGVeRiZQ8lgwAc%20TA8iAQIbjShTeaWWyOdzefbbmBxD5Q0qVSwYCBc5BPZ8JbqVWrNdq6wa4A6hTQAPQdmAAOj7lBllAWVRgAgQUGMYFQEGbwbIiZAtwA5AWfEuy27RVAJUvGCglzLPrU5qPx5Pp43xDqS1ltgvl6uEOuYJuPTAl4MYZ0D0egA)

Comment: This answer is better than mine because it has less indirection. I had thought about doing this but I remember having issues with it in certain scenarios but it works nice here

Comment: To be honest, your answer was the first one I thought about! In fact I was writing it when you both posted your answers so I left the only one missing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use function overloaing.

```
const TextInputTypes = [
    "text",
    "number",
    "password",
    "email",
    "tel",
    "url",
    "search",
    "color",
    "date",
    "time",
    "datetime-local",
    "month",
    "week",
    "range",
    "file",
] as const;
const CheckboxTypes = ["checkbox", "radio"];
const SelectTypes = ["select"] as const;
type TextType = (typeof TextInputTypes)[number];
type CheckType = (typeof CheckboxTypes)[number] | (typeof SelectTypes)[number];
type InputType = TextType | CheckType;

type PromptOptions<T extends InputType> = {
    input: T;
    placeholder: string;
    entries: { value: string; text: string }[];
};

const isCheckboxType = (typeString: string): typeString is CheckType => (CheckboxTypes as string[]).includes(typeString)

function foo (name: string, options: PromptOptions<TextType>): string
function foo (name: string, options: PromptOptions<CheckType>): string[]
function foo (name: string, options: PromptOptions<TextType | CheckType>): string | string[]  {
  if (CheckboxTypes.includes(options.input as CheckType)) {
    // TODO
    return ''
  }

  // transformToDocument
  return []
}

const arrayExample = foo('test', {input: 'select', placeholder: 'test', entries: []})
const stringExample = foo('test', {input: 'text', placeholder: 'test', entries: []})
```

[image]Use function overloading.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use function overloads to detect the type of the `input` property and then return either a `string` or a `string[]`. Note that this requires changing from an anonymous function (`const foo = () => {}`) to a named function (`function foo() {}`).

```js
function isTextType(inputType:string):inputType is typeof TextInputTypes[number] {
    return (TextInputTypes as readonly string[]).includes(inputType);
}

type PromptOptions = {
    placeholder: string;
    entries: { value: string; text: string }[];
}
type TextTypePromptOptions = PromptOptions & {
    input: TextType;
};
type CheckTypePromptOptions = PromptOptions & {
    input: CheckType;
}


function foo(name:string, options:TextTypePromptOptions):string;
function foo(name:string, options:CheckTypePromptOptions):string[];
function foo(name:string, options:TextTypePromptOptions|CheckTypePromptOptions):string|string[] {
    if (isTextType(options.input)) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}

// const result1: string
const result1 = foo("", { placeholder: "", entries: [], input: "text" });
// const result2: string[]
const result2 = foo("", { placeholder: "", entries: [], input: "radio" });
```

This is easy to read and understand for simple cases like yours, but if you have many such arguments then it could get a little tedious to write out all the possible overloads.